# SQL Server Script to create grant scripts for user roles

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking for a script that I can run to create grant permissions for specific user roles in SQL Server, for example given a user role, the following would be generated for all tables and procedures in a database, so that it can be saved and reused later on:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[ResourceSource] TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;
GRANT INSERT ON [dbo].[ResourceSource] TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;
GRANT SELECT ON [dbo].[ResourceSource] TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;
GRANT UPDATE ON [dbo].[ResourceSource] TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;
GRANT DELETE ON [dbo].[ResourceSource] TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;
GRANT REFERENCES ON [dbo].[ResourceSource] TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;

GRANT EXECUTE ON dbo.TruncateAllTables TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;
GRANT EXECUTE ON import.CountryMerge TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;
GRANT EXECUTE ON import.CreateAllForeignKeys TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;
GRANT EXECUTE ON import.CreateAllIndexes TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates;
```

Comment: `select * from sys.tables` + `select * from sys.objects where type = 'P'`+ some dynamic sql is all you need....

Comment: I just found this question. Is this the same thing you are looking for?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300740/how-to-script-sql-server-database-role

Comment: Grant whole schemas

Comment: If it's truly all tables and procedures, just do something like `grant select to applicationresourcrsupdates`. Absent a securable, the grant applies to all appropriate securable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple of scripts that will generate the SQL for you.

```
SELECT 'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES ON [' + B.name + '].[' + A.name + '] TO [ApplicationResourcesUpdates]'
FROM sys.objects A JOIN sys.schemas B
ON A.schema_id = B.schema_id
WHERE A.type = 'U'

SELECT 'GRANT EXECUTE ON [' + B.name + '].[' + A.name + '] TO [ApplicationResourcesUpdates]'
FROM sys.objects A JOIN sys.schemas B
ON A.schema_id = B.schema_id
WHERE A.type = 'P'
```

You would just need to execute the output using SSMS. Change the use/group to a variable if you plan to run this for more than one. Simple, but it works. Good for a once in a while type of situation.

Answer (score 0):

And to revoke permissions:

```
SELECT 'REVOKE SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, REFERENCES ON OBJECT::' + B.name + '.' + A.name + ' FROM [ApplicationResourcesUpdates]'
FROM sys.objects A JOIN sys.schemas B
ON A.schema_id = B.schema_id
WHERE A.type = 'U'

SELECT 'REVOKE EXECUTE ON OBJECT::' + B.name + '.' + A.name + ' TO ApplicationResourcesUpdates'
FROM sys.objects A JOIN sys.schemas B
ON A.schema_id = B.schema_id
WHERE A.type = 'P'
```